# How to remove focus from button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I have a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonClick" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/imageView_bg"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

button_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" 
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>

</selector>
```

imageView_bg.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_pressed" 
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_normal"/>

    </selector>
```

I want to click the view as a whole.Both button and imageview have pressed images . The button and imageview becomes pressed when click on RelativeLayout.
How is it possible?Using the above layout, the button and image view shows pressed images when press them separately.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

ON event of Relative layout click do,

```
button.perfomClick()
imagebutton.perfomClick()
```

hope it helps..

Comment: It does not wok for me.ImageView and Button shows pressed images when click on them separately.